# Javascript Fetch API response.blob() is empty but response show binary data

Tags: javascript, file, networking, fetch

I've developed a small backend service that does some operation on file a returns it back.
The backend service built with `FastAPI` which has a `FileResponse` module.

This service receives requests from a Javascript client with Fetch API like so:

```
const baseUrl = ...
const formdata = new FormData(event.target) // target is a form with input[type=file]
const response = await fetch(baseUrl, {method:'POST', body:formdata})
const blob = response.blob() ---> Blob {size: 0, type: ''}
```

The response headers indicated that there is a file sent back:

```
Connection: keep-alive
content-disposition: attachment; filename*=utf-8''05%2BDon_t%2BLeave%2BMe%20Alone%20%281%29%20%281%29%20%281%29.mid
Content-Length: 4575
Content-Type: audio/midi
Date: Wed, 09 Aug 2023 09:42:05 GMT
etag: 32530b90b4c8728727e6589cb8182640
last-modified: Wed, 09 Aug 2023 09:42:05 GMT
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Ive tried also getting the file with `response.arrayBuffer` but that just returned an empty array.

What am I missing here?

Comment: you know `response.blob()` returns a Promise, right ? did you try awaiting it before looking at its size ?

Comment: @Touffy yes. otherwise the log would be Promise<pending>

Comment: Whatever the headers say… is there _actually_ binary data in the response…?! Can you see it in the network inspector?

Comment: @deceze yes there binary data in the preview/response tab of the the specific request.